# Javascript localized measures (metres v. feet)?

Tags: javascript, localization

JavaScript in most browsers has the ability to do something like `Date.toLocaleDateString()`, as well there are localized Number and currency projections.

**Is there an elegant solution for doing the locale-same for units of measure?**  In this case feet (yards whatever) v. metres based upon browser Locale setting?

Comment: There is only one country that still officially uses imperial measures. So if you just use metric measures you've covered 95% of the world's population. ;-) If you really insist, then ask the visitor if they want US-centric measures or what everyone else uses. BTW, the US military and scientific communities use metric too, so imperial is only for US civilian use.

Comment: Just trying to be simple and future-proof. (I know...who would ever revert...)

Comment: Fair enough, but doing unit of measure conversions would be a bit like doing currency conversions (without the constantly changing exchange rate). But `(23.55).toLocaleString('en-us',{'minimumFractionDigits':2,'maximumFractionDigits':2})` giving `'7.18ft'` would be handy. ;-)